# Access to RPC console

Tags: json-rpc

I am new to Bitcoin, can anyone tell me how I can access to my RPC console and type in commands. I am using Bitcoin Core on my PC. If there is a tutorial for beginners to access to RPC please notify me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Step-by-Step tutorial

Set up bitcoin.conf.

```
rpcuser=user <br>
rpcpassword=password <br>
rpcallowip=172.28.128.1 # The ip of your machine. Use 127.0.0.1 if you use local machine<br>
```

Start a bitcoin client by

```
bitcoind -server=1 -daemon
```

Download [this library](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) and install it by running

```
python setup.py install
```

Create a python script to connect to RPC server.

```
from jsonrpc import ServiceProxy
access = ServiceProxy("http://user:password@172.28.128.4:8332")
print(access.getbalance())
```

Comment: Re: `rpcallowip=172.28.128.1 # The ip of your machine. Use 127.0.0.1 if you use local machine`; is the local host allowed by default? Also, could you provide clarification on whether using **both** *rpcallowip* lines - ie 172.28.128.1 **&** 127.0.0.1, respectively, is problematic in the above conf file eg? I.e. Is there any harm adding local machine in addition to the machine IP?

Comment: Yes, local host is allowed by default..

Answer (score 1):

1. [RPC @ Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list)
2. *Mastering Bitcoin" (A. Antonopoulos)
3. Open `console >`, type `help`

You'll need a [Bitcoin.conf](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin%23Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File) file setup, which lives in your home directory (what OS?)

[Full instruction guide](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bitcoin-QT then simply go to Help->Debug Window->Console. This gives you full RPC capability inside of the wallet. If you want to work with the data you output, then you will need to use an RPC wrapper of your choice.